# sObject type 'AccountContactRelation' is not supported

Tags: soql

We have a project were we have recently enabled the feature allowing one Contact to link to multiple Accounts.  We followed the directions according to the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_sales_shared_contacts_enable.htm) and in the Developer console I am successfully able to execute queries such as:

`SELECT Id, AccountId, ContactId FROM AccountContactRelation`

However, when I try and execute this query remotely, I simply receive the error message:

`sObject type 'AccountContactRelation' is not supported.`

All queries FROM Contact or Account are successful.  Does anyone know what I have to do to be able to query against `AccountContactRelation`?

I am not sure if it is relevant, but if I check the "Use Tooling API" checkbox in the developer console, I receive this same error for queries against AccountContactRelation, Contacts, and Accounts.

Answer (score 3):

To make use of `AccountContactRelation` in query, we first need to enable this feature from Setup menu.

From Setup, enter Account Settings in the Quick Find box, then select Account Settings.

Select **Allow users to relate a contact to multiple accounts**.

[image]

Check the reference document [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_sales_shared_contacts_enable.htm)

Comment: Any chance you tested this answer @Devendra? It doesn't appear to work at all (obviously, you'd need to enable Multiple Accounts, but that still doesn't seem to make AccountContactRelation work with the query endpoint).

(Also, the reference document you link to doesn't cover this question at all.)

Comment: @DominicScheirlinck were you able to solve this issue? Can you explain how the issue was fixed

Comment: @madawa I *think* I fixed this by upgrading the version of the API call I was making (to v39.0) - I think on earlier versions, the AccountContactRelation might be emulated through properties on either side, rather than appearing as a separate join-object.

If that fixes it for you, feel free to create an answer and get the points :)

Comment: @ Dominic Scheirlinck
You are correct. I just updated the code version from 26 to 39 and its worked.

Comment: Anyone know- Is it possible to enable AccountContactRelations via API?

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get it to work in a [Scratch Org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm) you'll need the `ContactsToMultipleAccounts` feature enabled.

For example your `project-scratch-def.json` would contain something along the lines of:

```
{
  "orgName": "Acme",
  "edition": "Enterprise",
  "features": ["ContactsToMultipleAccounts"]
}
```

Comment: This does successfully check the box in that screenshot shown in @Devendra's answer. I'm on API 51 and could swear I still got the `'AccountContactRelation' is not supported` error and had to manually uncheck and re-check before I could push my changes